# Admob: add timer before user can close the ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have an unity app, and able to integrate with AdMob.
But whenever Interstitial ad is shown, I want to have a count down timer saying "You can skip this ad after x seconds".
How can I achieve this in my app?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the ads provided by Admob. You cannot customize that issue.

Answer (score 0):

if it is an ad from admob network, then you do not have the option to autoclose.

if it is served from your own campaign, you can add some codes to your creatives, check this out, [Admob Sample code for automatically closing an interstitial](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1656921?hl=en)